# Cannot read property 'fontWeight' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a simple quiz application.
It was working fine until I try to edit the font for the selected radio button`var labelStyle = userpick.style.fontWeight;`

Anyone able to spot the problem??

Also, if possibe, suggestion to improve the code?

I have made some new changes to the checkAnswer function

```js
// define all the elements
var content = $("content");
var questionContainer = $("question");
var choicesContainer = $("choices");
var scoreContainer = $("score");
var submitBtn = $("submit");

//init variables
var currentQuestion = 0;
var score = 0;
var askingQuestion = true;
//shortcut for document.getElementById
function $(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

//askQuestion Function to load question into id = question
function askQuestion (){
  var choices = quiz[currentQuestion].choices;
  var choicesHtml = "";

  //loop through chocies and create a radio button
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
      choicesHtml += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'quiz" + currentQuestion +
                    "' id = 'choice" + (i + 1) + 
                    "' value ='" + choices[i] + "'>" + 
                    "<label for ='choice" + (i + 1) + "'>" + choices[i] + "</label></br>";   
  }
  //load the Question
  questionContainer.textContent = "Q" + (currentQuestion + 1) + ". " + quiz[currentQuestion].question;

  //load the choices
  choicesContainer.innerHTML = choicesHtml;

  //setup for the first time
  if(currentQuestion === 0){
    scoreContainer.textContent = "Score : 0 right answer out of " +
                                  quiz.length + " possible.";
    submitBtn.textContent = "Submit Answer";
  }
}

//checkAnswer function to match user input with quiz.correctAnswer

 

function checkAnswer(){
  //
  if (askingQuestion){
    submitBtn.textContent = "Next Question";
    askingQuestion = false;
  
  //determine if radio button is clicked
  var userpick;
  var correctIndex;
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("quiz" + currentQuestion);
    for (var i = 0  ; i < radios.length; i++){
      if(radios[i].checked){
      //if radio button is checked
        userpick = radios[i].value;
      }
      if(radios[i].value == quiz[currentQuestion].correct){
        correctIndex = i;
      }
    }
    //if they got it right or wrong
  var labelStyle = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[correctIndex].style;
      labelStyle.fontWeight = "bold";
    if (userpick == quiz[currentQuestion].correctAnswer) {
        score++;
        labelStyle.color = "green";
    }else{
        labelStyle.color = "red";
    }

    scoreContainer.textContent = "Score: "+ score + "right answers out of "+
                               quiz.length + " possible.";
  }

  function showFinalResults(){
    content.innerHtml = "<h2> You've completed the quiz</h2" +
                        "<h2> Below are your results </h2>" + 
                        "<h2>" + score + " out of " + quiz.length +
                        "questions, " + Math.round(score/quiz.length * 100) + "% </h2>";

  }


}

window.addEventListener("load", askQuestion, false);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer, false);


var quiz =  [{"question": "Question 1: Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's",
                     "choices": ["A: largest railway station",
                               "B: highest railway station",
                               "C: longest railway station",
                               "D: None of the above"],
                     "correctAnswer": 0
                    },
                    {"question": "Question 2: Entomology is the science that studies",
                     "choices": ["A: Behavior of human beings",
                               "B: Insects",
                               "C: The origin and history of technical and scientific terms",
                               "D: The formation of rocks"],
                     "correctAnswer": 1
                    },
                    {"question": "Question 3: Friction can be reduced by changing from",
                     "choices": ["A: sliding to rolling",
                               "B: rolling to sliding",
                               "C: potential energy to kinetic energy",
                               "D: dynamic to static"],
                     "correctAnswer": 0
                    },
                    {"question": "Question 4: For seeing objects at the surface of water from a submarine under water, the instrument used is",
                     "choices": ["A: kaleidoscope",
                               "B: spectroscope",
                               "C: periscope",
                               "D: telescope"],
                     "correctAnswer": 2
                    },
                    {"question": "Question 5: Galileo was an Italian astronomer who",
                     "choices": ["A: developed the telescope",
                               "B: discovered four satellites of Jupiter",
                               "C: discovered that the movement of pendulum produces a regular time measurement",
                               "D: All of the above"],
                     "correctAnswer": 3
                    },
                    {"question": "Question 6: Habeas Corpus Act 1679",
                     "choices": ["A: states that no one was to be imprisoned without a writ or warrant stating the charge against him",
                               "B: provided facilities to a prisoner to obtain either speedy trial or release in bail",
                               "C: safeguarded the personal liberties of the people against arbitrary imprisonment by the king's orders",
                               "D: All of the above"],
                     "correctAnswer": 3
                    },
                    {"question": "Question 7: For galvanizing iron which of the following metals is used?",
                     "choices": ["A: Aluminium",
                               "B: Lead",
                               "C: Zinc",
                               "D: Copper"],
                     "correctAnswer": 2
                    }];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang = "en">

 <title> Quiz </title>
</head>
<body> 
 
 <div class = "page-header">
  <h1>Simple Javascript Quiz</h1>
 </div> 
 <div id = "content">
  <h3 id = "question"> </h3>
  <div id = "choices"> </div>
  <button id = "submit">Submit</button>
  <p id ="score"></p>
 </div> 
<script src = 'quiz2.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend once someone digs through your code and finds the problem, you post to `codereview` for the suggestions part.

Answer (score 1):

```
userpick.style.fontWeight;
```

> Cannot read property 'fontWeight' of undefined

That means that `userpick.style` is `undefined`.

Relevant code:

```
var userpick;
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
  if(radios[i].checked){
    userpick = radios[i].value;
```

If no radio was checked, `userpick.style.fontWeight` would throw, but the error would be

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

That means that there is some checked radio, so `userpick` is not undefined.

But `userpick.style` is undefined. And thats because the `value` of a radio is a string, and by default strings have no `style` property.

Probably, you want `userpick` to be the checked radio, not its value

```
var userpick;
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length && !userpick; ++i)
  if(radios[i].checked)
    userpick = radios[i];
```

However, let me introduce [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) and the [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked):

```
var userpick = document.querySelector(".quiz" + currentQuestion + ":checked");
```

Comment: you are right. didnt' pay attention to the string property. I am only focusing on HTML and javascript now. still haven't added any CSS so pseudo-class is not used.

Comment: @BrianHo I meant you can use the `:checked` pseudo-class to find the checked radio, instead of iterating all radios manually.

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of your code:

```
 var radios = document.getElementsByName("quiz" + currentQuestion);
    for (var i = 0  ; i < radios.length; i++){
      if(radios[i].checked){
      //if radio button is checked
        userpick = radios[i].value;
      }
    }
    //if they got it right or wrong
  var labelStyle = userpick.style.fontWeight;
```

You put the VALUE of the selected radio button in the userpick variable. The style object is only available on a DOM element. Which is not the value of said element.

If you do: `userpick = radios[i];` instead, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

`var labelStyle = usepick.style.fontWeight;`

fontWeight is a string type.

However, later, you try `labelStyle.color = "green"`

The color property doesn't exist in a string.

However, worse than that userpick is a string itself!

This is because userpick = radios[i].value  - value is a string type.

**Most Importantly** - you are trying to set fontWeight or color of a radio button - there is no text node in a radio button, so it won't make any visible difference - you need to select the label associated with that button and set THAT font weight and color.

Comment: now I realize I am selecting a string so its not working.
I have tried to add a new variable called selectedIndex = i.
then i set the var labelStyle = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[selectedIndex].style.fontWeight;
It doesn't work though :(

Comment: i have added something new to the checkAnswer function but it's still giving me a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.